# Is open distro fully supported by AWS elasticsearch?

Tags: aws-elasticsearch

I tried the SQL plugin as explained in the official documentation.

https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/sql/partiql/

I added the records and then used this query:

```
SELECT e.name AS employeeName,
       p.name AS projectName
FROM employees_nested AS e,
       e.projects AS p
```

The above query do not return anything. If I change the query to something like this...

```
SELECT e.name AS employeeName 
FROM employees_nested AS e
```

It returns the 3 records as expected.

Comment: How many results does `SELECT name FROM projects` return?

Comment: That query does not return anything because projects table is part of employees_nested and therefore is using the e.projects prefix.

Comment: Whoops! I originally saw it as a separate collection and not a nested collection.  Does Example #2 fail to return the results as well?